# Kubernetes worker Status Not Ready

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes

i have a problem issues with Kubernetes worker, i am have 2 machines first as master and second as worker (node). ubuntu server  Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
when i run the following command:

```
 kubectl describe node  kubernetes-worker
```

the following output:

```
    Name:               kubernetes-worker
    Roles:              
    Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=kubernetes-worker
                    kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    role=worker
    Annotations:        flannel.alpha.coreos.com/backend-data: {"VtepMAC":"82:22:c1:fa:c8:61"}
                    flannel.alpha.coreos.com/backend-type: vxlan
                    flannel.alpha.coreos.com/kube-subnet-manager: true
                    flannel.alpha.coreos.com/public-ip: 192.168.1.36
                    kubeadm.alpha.kubernetes.io/cri-socket: /var/run/dockershim.sock
                    node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: 0
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: true
     CreationTimestamp:  Mon, 02 Dec 2019 09:31:37 +0000
      Taints:             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoSchedule
      Unschedulable:      false
      Conditions:
  Type             Status    LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason              Message
  ----             ------    -----------------                 ------------------                ------              -------
  MemoryPressure   Unknown   Sat, 28 Dec 2019 15:31:21 +0000   Mon, 30 Dec 2019 06:31:26 +0000   NodeStatusUnknown   Kubelet stopped posting node status.
  DiskPressure     Unknown   Sat, 28 Dec 2019 15:31:21 +0000   Mon, 30 Dec 2019 06:31:26 +0000   NodeStatusUnknown   Kubelet stopped posting node status.
  PIDPressure      Unknown   Sat, 28 Dec 2019 15:31:21 +0000   Mon, 30 Dec 2019 06:31:26 +0000   NodeStatusUnknown   Kubelet stopped posting node status.
  Ready            Unknown   Sat, 28 Dec 2019 15:31:21 +0000   Mon, 30 Dec 2019 06:31:26 +0000   NodeStatusUnknown   Kubelet stopped posting node status.
Addresses:
  InternalIP:  192.168.1.36
  Hostname:    kubernetes-worker
Capacity:
 cpu:                2
 ephemeral-storage:  130551876Ki
 hugepages-1Gi:      0
 hugepages-2Mi:      0
 memory:             3918032Ki
 pods:               110
Allocatable:
 cpu:                2
 ephemeral-storage:  120316608723
 hugepages-1Gi:      0
 hugepages-2Mi:      0
 memory:             3815632Ki
 pods:               110
System Info:
 Machine ID:                 c87a16d69ec94e03a8a281b2d54c722c
 System UUID:                F493BA8E-F779-234F-AC40-C4899AC930B9
 Boot ID:                    f9b6eb1e-0a6b-4765-b8d6-1e5527a7f970
 Kernel Version:             4.15.0-70-generic
 OS Image:                   Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
 Operating System:           linux
 Architecture:               amd64
 Container Runtime Version:  docker://18.9.7
 Kubelet Version:            v1.16.3
 Kube-Proxy Version:         v1.16.3
PodCIDR:                     10.244.1.0/24
PodCIDRs:                    10.244.1.0/24
Non-terminated Pods:         (2 in total)
  Namespace                  Name                           CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  AGE
  ---------                  ----                           ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  kube-system                kube-flannel-ds-amd64-ssk8h    100m (5%)     100m (5%)   50Mi (1%)        50Mi (1%)      51d
  kube-system                kube-proxy-965g2               0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         51d
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource           Requests   Limits
  --------           --------   ------
  cpu                100m (5%)  100m (5%)
  memory             50Mi (1%)  50Mi (1%)
  ephemeral-storage  0 (0%)     0 (0%)
`
```

what the problem and how i resolve this, this happened from nowhere i don't touch any settings or something.
thank for help.

**Update**

```
<pre> 947 summary_sys_containers.go:47] Failed to get system container stats for "/system.slice/docker.service": failed to get cgroup stats Jan 23 07:26:27 kubernetes-master kubelet[947]: E0123 07:26:27.344712 947 summary_sys_containers.go:47] Failed to get system container stats for "/system.slice/docker.service": failed to get cgroup stats Jan 23 07:26:37 kubernetes-master kubelet[947]: E0123 07:26:37.446034 947 summary_sys_containers.go:47] Failed to get system container stats for "/system.slice/docker.service": failed to get cgroup stats </pre>
```

Comment: Hi, check the logs of `kubelet` it will tell you more Information

Comment: i have a more logs : <pre> 947 summary_sys_containers.go:47] Failed to get system container stats for "/system.slice/docker.service": failed to get cgroup stats
Jan 23 07:26:27 kubernetes-master kubelet[947]: E0123 07:26:27.344712     947 summary_sys_containers.go:47] Failed to get system container stats for "/system.slice/docker.service": failed to get cgroup stats
Jan 23 07:26:37 kubernetes-master kubelet[947]: E0123 07:26:37.446034     947 summary_sys_containers.go:47] Failed to get system container stats for "/system.slice/docker.service": failed to get cgroup stats
 </pre>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start kubelet with below flags.

```
--runtime-cgroups=/systemd/system.slice --kubelet-cgroups=/systemd/system.slice
```

Comment: thank guys it's working now

Comment: Can you accept the answer if it worked?